# Find the length of the curve intersection of cone and cylinder

Tags: vector-analysis

Given a cone z = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ which intersects with $x^2+y^2-2ay=0$ and $a>0$ . If C is the curve of that intersection, then set up the integral or integrals for finding the length of this curve. I thought about a line integral but I wasn't able to parametrize the curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given $x^2+y^2-2ay$ describes a upright vertical cylinder centered on the $y$-axis at $(0,a,0)$ with radius $a$. Being vertical means the axis of the cylinder is parallel to $z$-axis.

The natural parametrization of any point of the 2-dim surface of the cylinder is $(\text{angle}, \text{height})$:$$(a \sin t,\, a(1 - \cos t),\, z)$$ where the parameter $t$ is the angle made with $-\hat{y}\,$ such that $t = 0$ starts at the origin and rotates counter-clockwise viewed from above.

Now, the intersection of the cylinder with the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ conveniently gives $z = \sqrt{2ay}$ just by definition of $x^2 + y^2 - 2ay = 0$. Therefore, the intersection curve $\mathcal{C}$ can be parametrized as$$a(\sin t,\, 1 - \cos t,\, \sqrt{2(1- \cos t)})$$

Now you can set up the arc length integral as
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{\mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 + \mathrm{d}z^2} &= \int \sqrt{ \bigl( \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \bigr)^2 + \bigl( \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} \bigr)^2 + \bigl( \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \bigr)^2 }\,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= a \sqrt{ (\cos t)^2 + (\sin t)^2 + \frac{ \sin^2 t }{2(1 - \cos t) } } \,\mathrm{d}t \\
& = \frac{ a }{ \sqrt{2} } \int \sqrt{3 + \cos t} \,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

I guess this is a calculus exercise that only requires you to set up the integral. In case you haven't notice, the intersection $\mathcal{C}$ is an ellipse, and the this is an elliptic integral that has no closed form in elementary functions.

The complete curve length (integrating $t = 0$ to $2\pi$) is $4\sqrt{2}\,a\,E\left(\frac12\right)$, where $E(m)$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the 2nd kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) (if you prefer wiki, [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind)). Numerically, $E\left(\frac12\right) \approx 1.350643881\ldots$

Comment: Your guess is correct, I had misunderstood the exercise, I was simply asked to set up the integral and I was able to parametrize the curve in the end, having found the integral you too found, thanks anyway!

Comment: @JuanGarcia I'm glad that you solved it yourself. Then maybe you can consider deleting this question, or accept my answer, or post your own solution and accept it. That way this post can be "concluded" and not clog up the queue of the system.

Comment: I did it, I am not so acquainted  with this page still

Comment: Not a problem. In my early days (and now still) I often unintentionally conduct myself in ways that more experienced users consider uninformed. I actually enjoy having this nice correspondence with you.

Comment: Haha I am glad you do, so do I! It's difficult sometimes to get used to a new page